# How to replace a string with another string and the replaced string will have arguments of first string in it using RegExp

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string

```
String SQL = "SELECT POSITION('Bengal' IN STRING) from delivery";
```

I want to replace the POSITION() function from the SQL string with this String **INSTR(STRING,'Bengal')**. And in the POSITION function of SQL String 'Bengal' and STRING is not a fixed values it will change as per user requirement but POSITION,the open braces "(",IN and closing braces ")" is static.
The final out put has to be look like this using Regular Expression.

```
String SQL ="SELECT INSTR(STRING,'Bengal') from delivery";
```

So in the string if it repeats two times then it has to replace two time with corresponding arguments into the same string SQL.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect there can be nested parentheses.

Comment: no it won't be because its a function,it won't allow nested parentheses

Comment: It's really hard to get 100% correct if the string can contain anything including (for example) SQL.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, use this Regex:

```
SQL = SQL.replaceAll("POSITION\\((.*?) IN ([A-Z]+)\\)", "INSTR($2, $1)");
```

Note, however, that it will work only for simple cases of the input String, if the first parameter is some expression and second is something more complex, it may not work. It will even work for multiple `POSITION` expressions in the query, such as this:

```
String SQL = "SELECT POSITION('Bengal''s something IN d' IN STRING), POSITION('text' IN STRINGX) from delivery";
SQL = SQL.replaceAll("POSITION\\((.*?) IN ([A-Z]+)\\)", "INSTR($2, $1)");
// SQL now contains: "String SQL = "SELECT INSTR(STRING, 'Bengal''s something IN d'), INSTR(STRINGX, 'text') from delivery";"
```

If you want to completely correctly replace the function call, use proper sqlparser. In the past I used [JSQLParser](https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser). It can handle even subselects as `POSITION` parameters with nested `POSITION` calls.

Comment: :Thanks for the post but the out put is different rather than what i expected, the out put is :SELECT INSTR(2, 1), INSTR(2, 1) from delivery.But i want it like this SELECT INSTR(STRINGX, 'text'), INSTR(STRINGX, 'text') from delivery.

Comment: When i used the above directly inside the java code its working fine but when i add the pattern inside mysql data base,its not giving the expected output,its giving the same output as my input.

Comment: How do you put it to mysql database? You should use regexp package, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql. I'm not an MySQL expert, your question is tagged `java`.